# Where can I find Rademacher's wrong disproof of the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

Mathematical folklore has it that the famous algebraist Hans Rademacher once came up with a wrong disproof of the Riemann Hypothesis, which was initially believed by another famous mathematician, Carl Siegel. I vaguely remember that they say Rademacher's error was that he mistakenly assumed that logarithms of complex numbers are uni-valued.

But where can I find this particular work of Rademacher?

I would want to go over it in detail and I imagine something could be learned from it. A Google search didn't yield anything meaningful.

Comment: The manuscript was submitted in 1943 to the American Mathematical Society’s Transactions, but withdrawn by Rademacher before publication. Here is the [story](https://www.amazon.com/Riemann-Hypothesis-Greatest-Unsolved-Mathematics/dp/0374529353) (page 109)

Comment: @ Carlo Beenacker, so after the manuscript was withdrawn by its author, it couldn't be found anywhere ?

Comment: Another [quote](https://books.google.nl/books?id=jXbWiz6VynYC&pg=PT147): _Rademacher was terribly embarrased by the ordeal and never spoke of it again. [...] It was well known that no one was to mention the words "Riemann hypothesis" in his presence._ So I would imagine any copies of this withdrawn manuscript would have been well hidden, the AMS perhaps still has a copy in their files...

Comment: "... they say Rademacher's error": can you tell us who "they" are? (Maybe @CarloBeenakker has some idea?) If that information is correct, then Rademacher's embarrassment over such a rookie mistake becomes very understandable.

Comment: @ToddTrimble -- Rademacher's error was noticed by [Carl Siegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Ludwig_Siegel)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you. The Wikipedia page doesn't mention anything about the Rademacher story; do you know of a place in print where the error is discussed?

Comment: it's in the book linked to in the first comment; I copied the page, you can find it [here](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Rademacher.png)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks!  So apparently, reading that description, it was a wrong proof (by contradiction), not a wrong *disproof* as in the post above, i.e., Rademacher was attempting to prove RH true, not false.

Comment: it was a disproof; I have collected the available info in the answer box.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I am sorry to belabor this point, but I don't understand why you are calling it a disproof. Maybe you are using the word differently from how I'm using it. "... if you assume the Riemann Hypothesis is *false* [my emphasis], and then do this, this, and this, and you get a contradiction, then it must be true." So based on that, the conclusion would have been RH is true. In other words, based on the description that you quoted, it sounds as if Rademacher was trying to prove RH is true, via a proof by contradiction. Not a disproof by contradiction.

Comment: Hi @ToddTrimble --- I am relying on the April 30, 1945 Time Magazine as the authoritative source (in the absence of other contemporary sources); it says _"A wire from the society's secretary, University of Pennsylvania Professor John R. Kline, asked Editor Albert to stop the presses: a paper disproving the Riemann hypothesis was on the way. Its author: Professor Hans Adolf Rademacher, a refugee German mathematician now at Penn."_

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you very much. I guess that should suffice for now, although I have to wonder if something got garbled in someone's transmission.

Answer (score 10):

This does not directly answer the question, but gives the details of the story, including the source of the error.

*[Time Magazine, Monday April 30, 1945:](http://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,797441,00.html)*
 <sub>The year is erroneously given as 1943 in the book linked to below</sub>

> A sure way for any mathematician to achieve immortal fame would be to
>   prove or disprove the Riemann hypothesis. This baffling theory, which
>   deals with prime numbers, is usually stated in Riemann's symbolism as
>   follows: "All the nontrivial zeros of the zeta function of *s*, a
>   complex variable, lie on the line where $\sigma$ is ½ -- ($\sigma$
>   being the real part of *s*)." The theory was propounded in 1859 by
>   Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann (who revolutionized geometry and laid
>   the foundations for Einstein's theory of relativity). No layman has
>   ever been able to understand it and no mathematician has ever proved
>   it.
>
> One day last month electrifying news arrived at the University of
>   Chicago office of Dr. Adrian A. Albert, editor of the Transactions of
>   the American Mathematical Society. A wire from the society's
>   secretary, University of Pennsylvania Professor John R. Kline, asked
>   Editor Albert to stop the presses: a paper disproving the Riemann
>   hypothesis was on the way. Its author: Professor Hans Adolf
>   Rademacher, a refugee German mathematician now at Penn.
>
> On the heels of the telegram came a letter from Professor Rademacher
>   himself, reporting that his calculations had been checked and
>   confirmed by famed Mathematician Carl Siegel of Princeton's Institute
>   for Advanced Study. Editor Albert got ready to publish the historic
>   paper in the May issue. U.S. mathematicians, hearing the wildfire
>   rumor, held their breath. Alas for drama, last week the issue went to
>   press without the Rademacher article. At the last moment the professor
>   wired meekly that it was all a mistake; on rechecking. Mathematician
>   Siegel had discovered a flaw (undisclosed) in the Rademacher
>   reasoning. U.S. mathematicians felt much like the morning after a
>   phony armistice celebration. Sighed Editor Albert: ''The whole thing
>   certainly raised a lot of false hopes."

The "undisclosed" flaw found by Siegel is identified on page 109 of [The Riemann Hypothesis: The Greatest Unsolved Problem in Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0374529353):

[image]